# using a win form combo box Items.AddRange method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, addrange

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to add to the Items collection of a combo box control using the AddRange method.  The method takes an `object[]` but when I pass it the name of the array which has been intialized with some values, it complains:

> The best overloaded method match for `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])` has some invalid arguments.

The class defining the objects in my array is very simple:

```
public class Action
{
   public string name;
   public int value;
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return name;
   }
}

and my array is declared such:

    public Action[] actions = new Action[] {
    new Action() { name = "foo", value = 1 },
    new Action() { name = "bar", value = 2 },
    new Action() { name = "foobar", value = 3 }
};
```

this is where I try to call `AddRange`:

```
combobox1.Items.AddRange(actions);
```

and that's the line that it's complaining about - is there some step I'm missing to be able to do this?  it works fine when I'm just adding a simple `string[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried it out in a .NET C# test project as below & it works fine.
 The sample code is as below:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Action[] actions = new Action[]
            {
new Action() { name = "foo", value = 1 },
new Action() { name = "bar", value = 2 },
new Action() { name = "foobar", value = 3 }
            };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(actions);
        }

    }

    public class Action
    {
        public string name;
        public int value;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

So you need to tell us where have you declared the actions object.

Comment: ugh, you're right, it does work - I had mistyped something and I was looking for explanation in the wrong place - thanks Ganesh